# Async Handler for Update Contract States Operation encountered some errors,

Tags: asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

The Job called "Contract States job" fails every times it runs with the following message.

> "*Async Handler for Update Contract States Operation encountered some
>   errors, see log for more detail.Detail:* "

I've tried setting trace to verbose even but can't see the log, or any errors why this job is failing every time. This job is crucial to the contract entity as it need to renew (via plugin) promptly so to generate contract-detail lines in time for other process to follow.

Could someone please point me to this log or how I can trap this error causing this job to fail?

Comment: You can enable tracing (which produces very verbose logs) by following this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490

Comment: Could find some trace entries eventually about Contact totals not matching the contractdetail lines total, after investigation they all seem to be cancelled or expired contract (the system seems to zero these out) - after updating the totals again using SQL manually the 'update contract states' job seems to continue running successfully. any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace displayed errors on some contracts not being able to update state because the TotalPrice was not equal to the sum of its contract lines. Further diffing showed that another "unsupported script" would change contract states - thus causing this operation to fail on these contracts.

- The fix was to have a look at the "unsupported script" rather.